# Putting javascript for input tag in php function :)

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php function which reloads one page in hided iframe before real redirection is done after input button is clicked.

```
function button_confirm_order_params() {
  $url = "somepagetoreloadinbackground.php";
  $alert = "alert('you will be redirected to ext. page')";
  return "onclick=\"document.all.myFrame.src='$url'; $alert;\"";
}
```

Everything works good, however I would like to use something more beatiful than browser's alert.
Is this possible to put in there any javascript, so I would be able to show a good-looking pop-up? It's all inside >input< tag and I have no idea, how to get this through.

Comment: Google for some alert replacement plugins like e.g. http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/

Answer (score 0):

Look up sweet alert: http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/

Or one of my favourites toastr: http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html

Comment: Yeah, I found the sweet alert and that's what I would like to use :)
However the thing is, it needs <script>swal()</script> to start and I don't know if I can use it inside of input button.

Comment: I think youre going about this the wrong way, in your button add this code `onclick="alert()"` and then in your script have the alert function open sweet alert, look for a few examples it should be easy enough